# SpringSecurity : decode a password encoded with PasswordEncoder

Tags: spring-security, password-encryption

I have stored (and encoded) an email password. I have used PasswordEncoder (Spring security).

```
passwordEncoder.encode(password);
```

Now I need to decode it in order to use it in javax mail. (the password is used to connect to the email provider(yahoo, gmail, etc).
Is there a way to decode this password?

Comment: There isn't... Passwords are encrypted using a one way algorithm, it isn't the password that is stored but a calculated hash of the password. So there isn't a way to recover the actual password. As it should...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does Spring provides a password encode/decode api? or do you know a robust java password encode/decode api?

Comment: you can use jasypt, but being able to decrypt passwords is a possible security breach.

Comment: A must read for password encryption/decryption is http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PasswordEncoder](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html) interface support only encoding and matching which is the best way to deal with password as others too have suggested. You can use [StandardPBEStringEncryptor](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html) provided by [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) library as this library had transparent integration with Spring Security. Else you can roll out your own using Java Cryptography Extension's [Password Based Encryption (PBE)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) however before trying what you want to achieve with regards to password encryption you must definitely read [this](http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html).